# How to route user request to specific docker container based on the user id through IAP in GCP Kubernetes Engine

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, google-iap

I am trying to come up with a hello-world prototype for GCP Kubernetes Engine using IAP to allocate a container for a specific user and route all requests from this user to this container only. It is to protect user sensitive information in a totally isolated environment.

I followed "Enabling IAP for GKE" as @wilrof suggested, and got stuck in adding an iap block to the BackendConfig as follows;

```
apiVersion: cloud.google.com/v1  
kind: BackendConfig  
metadata:  
  name: config-default
  namespace: my-namespace  
spec:
  iap:
    enabled: true
    oauthclientCredentials:
      secretName: my-secret
```

When I run 'kubectl apply -f backendconfig.yaml', it complains that no matches for kind "BackendConfig" in version "cloud.google.com/v1". I changed the first line to cloud.google.com/v1beta1, then it says  namespaces "my-namespace" not found. Not sure where to go from here.

Comment: The first pointer is [Enabling IAP for GKE](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/enabling-kubernetes-howto), you enable IAP and use [Backendconfig](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/backendconfig) to set your ingress to direct it to the service/pod. please take a look at [**how to create a minimal, reproducible example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and provide more info in order to get a better answer!

Comment: @willrof going through the pointer, but got suck in BackendConfig...

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, I provided you an explanation for these pattern.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments:

> The first pointer is [Enabling IAP for GKE](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/enabling-kubernetes-howto), you enable IAP and use [Backendconfig](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/backendconfig) to set your ingress to direct it to the service/pod.

---

Then you updated your question, here is the troubleshooting for `BackendConfig`:

[Note](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/backendconfig): GKE versions 1.16.8-gke.3 and greater support the cloud.google.com/v1 CRD API version.

All lower GKE versions should use cloud.google.com/v1beta1.

- Since you tried running with v1 and got `no matches for kind "BackendConfig" in version "cloud.google.com/v1"` I presume you are running a version older than 1.16.8-gke.3.
- As for the error `namespaces "my-namespace" not found`, make sure your working namespace is called "my-namespace", remember the default namespace for kubernetes is `default`.

---

**Reproduction on v1.15.11-gke.12:**

- I first try to deploy as v1 as in your `backendconfig.yaml` example:

```
$ kubectl apply -f backendconfig.yaml 
error: unable to recognize "backendconfig.yaml": no matches for kind "BackendConfig" in version "cloud.google.com/v1"
```

- changed to `v1beta1` and applied:

```
$ cat backendconfig.yaml 
apiVersion: cloud.google.com/v1beta1
kind: BackendConfig  
metadata:  
  name: config-default
  namespace: my-namespace  
spec:
  iap:
    enabled: true
    oauthclientCredentials:
      secretName: my-secret

$ kubectl apply -f backendconfig.yaml 
Error from server (NotFound): error when creating "backendconfig.yaml": namespaces "my-namespace" not found
```

- Check the namespaces currently configured:

```
owilliam@owilliam:~/GKE/backendconfig$ kubectl get namespaces
NAME              STATUS   AGE
default           Active   5m35s
kube-node-lease   Active   5m37s
kube-public       Active   5m37s
kube-system       Active   5m37s
```

- I'll create the namespace `my-namespace` and try to apply again:

```
$ kubectl create namespace my-namespace
namespace/my-namespace created

$ kubectl apply -f backendconfig.yaml 
backendconfig.cloud.google.com/config-default created
```

If you still have any issue add a comment and we will dig further.